# how can you get a loop to shift an output on the screen c++

Tags: c++, loops, animation

I'm really finding it hard to word this problem so I'll do my best

basically I have an issue with producing a dynamic output where the output would shift on the screen based on criteria and new output would move up with it

this is what i have at the moment.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
int input;
cout<<"Please enter road distance"<<endl;
cin>>input;

while (input < 30)
{
    cout <<"|                     |                        |"<<endl;
    cout <<"|                                              |"<<endl;
    input++;
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

i just want to have an output of e.g.
[car]

i want this output to print in a loop and shift either up or down and keep shifting until it's out of the screen. like a bird's eyes view of a car and a raod

is there any other way around this? is there a topic i should research?
any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using some library for it (for instance ncurses?)

Comment: This question most probably is at least OS specific.

Comment: @Slava not neccessarily. If he uses some library, as cerkiewny perfectly suggested, that will wrap the platform-specific console behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can put std::cout in loop, based on "input", so it will shift your output more, for each iteration.

```
while (input < 30)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input; ++i) {
         std::cout << " "; 
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    input++;
}
```

Also, you might want to use standart "for" loop, instead of while, this is not good style of coding.

Comment: say _loop_ instead of _cycle_ :)